# TypeError: Cannot read property 'showModal' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I tried out this tutorial [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/dwmkerr/8MVLJ/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=8MVLJ)

I put this code in my angular controller

```
$scope.show = function () {
            ModalService.showModal({
                templateUrl: 'modal.html',
                controller: "ModalController"
            }).then(function (modal) {
                modal.element.modal();
                modal.close.then(function (result) {
                    $scope.message = "You said " + result;
                });
            });
        };
```

but i keep getting the error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'showModal' of undefined

I would like to know where is this ModalService and how do I get it to work on my project.Thank you

Comment: Did you inject ModalService in your controller?

Comment: Yes I did, this is what I have on my module registration angular.module('userManagement', ['ngImgCrop'], ['ModalService']);

Comment: It should be angular.module('userManagement', ['ngImgCrop','ModalService']);

Comment: Thank you, I changed it but I am still getting the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install a library in order to use that `ModalService`. You can download the library from the [original github repository](https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service). After installed, add `angularModalService` to your angular module and inject `ModalService` to your controller.

Comment: I did and I tried debugging to see if the script gets called, it does get called but it does not reach the self.showModal  part of the script

Comment: Thank you so much, I did this but I had forgotten to change the controller name. This worked